# SmtpClient send email error "Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender"

Tags: asp.net-core, exchange-server, smtpclient

I am trying to use SmtpClient send emails in my asp.net core application.

This is the code below:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(_configuration["mail.firm.com"]);
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
//client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
//client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mydomain\\myadminaccount", "11223344");

MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(_configuration["noreply@firm.com"]);

// Set email subject, body, to address logic
// ......
// End

try {
    client.Send(mailMessage);

    return true;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}

return false;
```

I found that:

1.On my local machine, debugging mode, running VS as Admin account, it works fine.

2.On my local machine, debugging mode, if I specify credentials, it does not work. give the 5.7.1 error message in exception message.

3.On the test server, debugging mode, running VS as Admin account, it works fine.

4.on the test server, deployed to IIS, IIS pool running as the same Admin account as VS, it does not work.

Can anyone see anything I did wrong or if I am missing anything?

Comment: Hi @Xiao Han, so what is the error message you received?

Comment: Thanks @Rena. the error is in the post's subject. that's what I received from the code's exception handler e.Message